# Solr 4.2.1 SSLinitializationException

Tags: solr

After upgrading to **Solr 4.2.1**, deploying the Solr war file to GlassFish version 3.1.1 results in the following error:

```
    2013-04-09 10:45:06,144 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter - Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
    2013-04-09 10:45:06,224 [main] ERROR org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore - null:org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLInitializationException: Failure initializing default system SSL context
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:368)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getSystemSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.java:204)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SchemeRegistryFactory.createSystemDefault(SchemeRegistryFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.SystemDefaultHttpClient.createClientConnectionManager(SystemDefaultHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.getConnectionManager(AbstractHttpClient.java:466)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClientUtil.setMaxConnections(HttpClientUtil.java:179)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
  at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:772)
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:55)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1214)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:281)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSystemSSLContext(SSLSocketFactory.java:366)     
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:770)
    ... 54 more
```

It seems like people have had this problem when using Solr version 4.2 and the bug fix release 4.2.1 was supposed to fix it (?). Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Had the same problems a few days ago. Solved it by downgrading to solr 4.1.0. But there is a solution (found it by googling my personally well known search terms once again ;) Just add two JVM options. Start glassfish with:

```
asadmin start-domain
```

and enter:

```
asadmin create-jvm-options -- -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=changeit
asadmin create-jvm-options -- -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
```

Don't forget to restart glassfish:

```
asadmin restart-domain
```

Tried it for myself and works like a charm. Obviously this is working only if you never changed those passwords before.

Comment: You do not need to downgrade the Solr version.  The same trick works with Solr 4.2.1 as well.

Comment: I downgraded, because I wanted to have the most current working version. 4.1.0 didn't need these entries it works perfectly fine without them.

Comment: I found that if Solr is deployed on GF on machine #1 and you're trying to access it with GF on a machine #2, the above mentioned JVM options should be added on machine #2. I've used this solution with great success on both a Solr 4.0.0 and a 4.4.0 setup.